# Enabling mouse and paste support in command line vim

Tags: macos, bash, command-line

I've found these two articles
http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/vimfaq2html3.pl
(see 31.13)
and
http://www.tummy.com/journals/entries/jafo_20060727_145450

But am unfamiliar with basic vim setup. Can anyone help me with a step by step instructions to making mouse usuage in command line mode automatically enabled? (and you will have good luck for a week if you can shed some light on enabling paste from OS to terminal window in VIM)

Note: Using latest mac os

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that Terminal.app has no mouse support, you'll need to use xterm in X11 to get mouse working.

I did find a 'plugin' for Terminal that claims to add mouse support, however it is in alpha and has no mention of 10.6. If it does work at all you'd probably need to run Terminal.app in 32 bit mode.
http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Utilities/MouseTerm.shtml

Comment: There's also an application called iTerm which does have mouse support, though I've found that it likes to use 3-5% CPU at idle, which can be annoying on a macbook.

Comment: Good to know that Terminal.app has no mouse support! Now, I've the iTerm2-1_0_0_20130811 (beta) which don't eat CPU on my MBP with Lion.

Comment: 2014-11-06, I tried MouseTerm and it worked for me in vim local, and in vim via ssh (I just added set mouse=a in the .vimrc). I'm on mac

Answer (score 5):

To enable mouse support in all modes put this in `~/.vimrc`:

```
set mouse=a
```

Answer (score 1):

Try starting `vim` like this:

```
screen vim
```

That should enable copy/paste with the mouse.
You might also want to set-up an alias in `~/.bashrc` for this.

Answer (score 0):

Just use [iTerm2](http://www.iterm2.com/#/section/home) instead of the default Terminal.app. It has lots of other features, but mouse support alone makes it worth the switch.